# How to enable verbose in yarn v1 only in production

Tags: node.js, heroku, yarnpkg, yarnrc

I am using yarn v1 and need to debug yarn install in Heroku. I [found](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/914#issuecomment-840900664) it's possible by adding `.yarnrc` file with content:

```
--install.verbose true
```

How can I enable verbose mode only for production? If I try this, it doesn't work:

```
--install.verbose ${NODE_ENV === 'production'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since yarn [allows](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/envvars/) NPM config with env variables.
You can setup `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose` inside your Heroku app.

For testing in your local machine:

Windows: `set NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose`

MacOS/Linux: `export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose`

Comment: I tried to add `NPM_CONFIG_VERBOSE=TRUE` locally, but when I run `yarn install` or `yarn run start` I don't see any verbose messages.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, the correct variable should be `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose`, also updated it in the answer.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't change.

Comment: Can you check once again if they variable is actually created. First run `set NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose` then `echo %NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL%`, because it is working in my machine

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/a/XCnmEQJ) is what I see if I try it out. `echo %NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL%` prints `%NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL%`

Comment: Wait I see you have a Mac, you need to run `export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose` then `echo %NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL%` to check if it's correct set.

Comment: it's still the [same](https://imgur.com/a/GoPhWyZ)

Comment: echo command not printing "verbose" means it's not setting correctly. Here's what I would say to try again, Open a new bash terminal -> Run only `export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose` then run `printenv` separately. Ensure that bash terminal in in project directory only

Comment: I set NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL, you can [see](https://imgur.com/a/WFMaFGk) it in console log, but verbose is not working.